# Wix toolset - how to right align text

Tags: wix

I'm using a customized version of thmutil theme for my Wix installer. For various reasons I want to right-align two text boxes ().
I can set the right end of the boxes but I cannot align the text so that it appears right-aligned.
Is there a way to modify the theme to support setting text alignment to left|center|right?
I thnk of an atribute like RightAligned="yes".

`<Text  X="-11" Y="11" Width="190" Height="30" FontId="1" Visible="yes" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.Title)</Text>
      <Text  X="-11" Y="40" Width="120" Height="17" FontId="3" Visible="yes" DisablePrefix="yes" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallVersion)</Text>`

Answer (score 0):

It is actually simple, but not directly documented. You can do it by adding the attribute `HexStyle="00000002"` to the `Text` element. This value corresponds to the Win32 constant `SS_RIGHT` which aligns a static text control content to the right.

Actually, you can do quite a lot of fancy stuff just with styles. Making borders, auto text ellipsis, and stuff...

For reference, here is a handy list of values for control styles and other constants: https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/master/include/winuser.rh. Of course you can also find this somewhere in the windows headers files.

Answer (score 0):

I used `RightAligned="yes"` attribute to align value in Text control to the right. (Wix Toolset v3.11)

```xml
<Control Id="ErrorLabel" Type="Text" X="30" Y="221" Width="300" Height="10" RightAligned="yes" Text="{\WixUI_Font_Error}!(loc.MissingValueError)">
    <Condition Action="hide" >NOT UI_VALUE_INVALID</Condition>
    <Condition Action="show" >UI_VALUE_INVALID</Condition>
</Control>
```